# Connect an LDAP realm with an AD domain, with the same name?

Tags: domain, ldap, kerberos

The situation is a separate group has created an LDAP domain.  We'll call it foo.bar.  (fyi, none of these are connected in any way to the Internet)  They also have a Windows domain and renamed it to foo.bar so, in their words, they can connect the two so it becomes one domain in the future.

At this point I'm lost because I don't know enough about LDAP on RHEL.  I know in AD that you can't just connect two domains with the same name and expect it to work because they are independent entities.  I got involved because they want to include the network I manage as well (an AD domain called good.bar)

Can someone confirm and maybe provide a reference for why this won't work and is a stupendously bad idea?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  MS AD is a collection of technologies (LDAP, Kerberos, DNS, and SMB/CIFS come immediately to mind).  You could put a trust in between the two AD domains.  As for connecting this other implementation of a LDAP directory, you need to provide more information.  You may be able to restructure the directory and use ADFS to link it to your AD, or your might have to totally rebuild it.